# Company Logo Shinks To Menu On Scroll

Tags: java, html, css, sticky, shrink

i had a file on my computer that the logo displayed in the header block will shrink to the sticky menu on scroll in other words (large image to small) i was wondering if anyone could assist me on how to do this! i would like the large logo to be in the center of the screen when the User first visits the website but as they scroll down to see the text the logo will shrink to the menu

Comment: There are many questions about that topic. So you need to explain why those questions and their answers didn’t help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Please share your HTML and CSS code. So then its easy to assist you.